# How to use python regex to remove ignore www. and only give the domain name?

Tags: python, regex, filtering, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to create a regex filter that will be used to sanitize domains that are processed by a python script.

The domains could possibly be just regular domain names

- something.com, some.something.com

or could have a url structure

- https://some.something.com

or could have url structure with www

- https://www.something.com

I currently have a crude regex to pull out domains out of these structures except I have not figured out a way to filter out the www. out.

```
(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-@]{,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,11}
```

This regex does a decent job grabbing domains out of urls, but when I try to do any kind of negative lookahead to remove the www.,I can't seem to get the desired result.  I've tried (?!www.) which only took away one w not all 3 and the ., any help figuring this out would be most appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be regex? Why not use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse)?

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/NZsPze/1) what you're looking for?

Comment: That one pulls out the domains that do not have the www. in them.  I want the domains with the www., but with the www. removed and just the second level domain "something.com" as the match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you absolutely have to use regex, it's better to use something designed for this - like the built-in `urlparse`. For one thing, your regex (and the one linked in the comments) won't match domains with non-ASCII characters.

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse # Python 2
>>> # from urllib.parse import urlparse # Python 3

>>> urlparse('http://www.some.domain/the/path')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.some.domain', path='/the/path', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse('http://www.some.domain/the/path').netloc
'www.some.domain'
```

Note that you might want to detect strings without `scheme` and add it:

```
>>> url = 'www.other.domain'
>>> urlparse(url)
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='www.other.domain', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> if not urlparse(url).scheme:
...     print urlparse('http://' + url)
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.other.domain', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

so you always get the domain in the `netloc` attribute of the `ParseResult`.

Once you have the domain separated out, if you want to remove the 'www.', there are any number of simple ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `urlparse`. Below is a sample of using it. I find it easy using `urlparse` over `regex`. urlparse gives you a class of parse results, and we can choose to extract the item we want and then do desired logical operations to extract the required host.

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> u1 = "https://example.com"
>>> d1 = urlparse(u1)
>>> d1.hostname
'example.com'

>>> u2 = 'https://www.123.com'
>>> h = urlparse(u2)
>>> host = h.hostname
>>> host[4:]
'123.com'

>>> u3 = 'something.com'
>>> d3 = urlparse(u3)
>>> if bool(d3.netloc):
...     print(d3)
... else:
...     print d3.path
... 
something.com

>>> d4 = 'somenew.net/pathis/123'
>>> u4 = urlparse(d4)
'somenew.net/pathis/123'
>>> u4.path.split('/')[0]
'somenew.net'
```

Comment: Down vote? Please explain the reason. That would help

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, but in general answers with just code are not as well received as answers that explain _why_ the approach you suggest is good. Also, your answer doesn't address the question fully, since it doesn't work for urls without a scheme (eg. `http://`) at the beginning, which the asker specifically mentions.

Comment: Appreciate your concern and Thanks for the comment. I am now thinking I would have written some theory for choosing urlparse oevr regex. I will address leftover part of the actual question. Again, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
((?:[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]\.|[a-z]\.)(?<!\bwww\.)
 (?:[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]\.|[a-z]\.)*
 (?:[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]|[a-z]))
```

And [examples](https://regex101.com/r/TmLhIa/4)

Explain:

- `[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]\.|[a-z]\.` match a label as described by [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3.5)
- `(?<!\bwww\.)` assert that the domain does not begin with `www.`. The part matched by `(?:[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]\.|[a-z]\.)` on the first line.

To match the simplest URL scheme (no auth part) as well, use [this](https://regex101.com/r/7bDX6h/3):

```
https?://
(?:www\.)?
((?:[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]\.|[a-z]\.)+
 (?:[a-z][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]|[a-z]))
```

Note that [`re.VERBOSE`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html?highlight=re%20verbose#re.VERBOSE) is used to ignore whitespace in the pattern so it look like more readable.

Comment: Note that this doesn't correctly handle domains that start with numbers, or that contain underscores or non-ascii characters, all of which are allowed. This is why it's not a good idea to write your own one-off parsing: there are so many subtleties.

Comment: It may not be a good idea to use regex to match URLs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
import re
from urllib.parse import urlparse



def parse_url(url):
    url_parse=urlparse(url)
    if not url_parse.scheme:
        url='http://' + url
        url_parse=urlparse(url)
    domain=urlparse(url).netloc
    domain = re.sub(r"^www.", "", domain)
    return(domain)

url='https://www.facebuk.com'
print(parse_url(url))
>>> facebuk.com

url='www.facebuk.com'
print(parse_url(url))
>>> facebuk.com
```